# How can I divide 24 music albums into 6 playlists such that the running time / length is as evenly distributed as possible?

Tags: algorithm, language-agnostic

*NOTE: I plan to implement this using Java, but any plain-English explanation of the steps needed in the logic is welcome and appreciated.*

I'm trying to come up with a way to divide a group of 24 music albums/records into 6 playlists such that the lengths/running time all 6 playlists are as close to each other as possible.

I initially thought that maybe I could find all possible permutations of the problem and then work out a logic that will analyze which is the best division. I even created a thread to ask for help for it yesterday ([I have 24 items that I need to separate into 6 sets of 4. What algorithm can I use to find all possible combinations?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23679648/i-have-24-items-that-i-need-to-separate-into-6-sets-of-4-what-algorithm-can-i-u)). However, when I got close to finding a solution, I realized that just finding all permutations of the problem will take incredibly long to run, so that approach seem impractical.

So I was wondering, is there a faster way to approach such a problem?

Given that these are the running times of the albums in question (in MM:SS format), what is the fastes way for me to find the division of albums into 6 playlists of 4 such that the lengths of each of the playlists is as close to each other as possible?

```
39:03 
41:08 
41:39 
42:54 
44:31 
44:34 
44:40 
45:55 
45:59 
47:06 
47:20 
47:53 
49:35 
49:57 
50:15 
51:35 
51:50 
55:45
58:10 
58:11 
59:48 
59:58   
60:00 
61:08
```

I did the math and considering the total time for all the albums, having 6 playlists that run at 200 minutes and 49 seconds would be perfect... but since the individual album lengths probably don't allow for that exact of a division, what would be the most exact possible division is my question.

NOTE: I could actually do this manually and get a close enough approximation that would suffice, but I am still really interested on how it could be done through a program.

Thanks!

Comment: I suggest that you start by trying to describe the steps of an algorithm in English. Don't worry about which programming language you might eventually implement it in.

Comment: @Code-Guru True. Sorry. It's just I have experience with answers being posted in code that I couldn't understand which is why I thought to specifiy that I would be doing this in Java.

Comment: I found this paper which uses genetic algorithms: http://scholar.google.com/scholar?cluster=6817947427968789639&hl=en&as_sdt=0,5&sciodt=0,5 . You need to define precisely what is meant by "as close to each other as possible", since that is only unambiguous for a partition into 2 sets. The paper I cite uses the Euclidean norm, while the problem cited by @hammar uses "least maximum"; another metric sometimes used is "difference between largest and smallest".

Comment: @rici this seems interesting! It details exactly the kind of problem I want to solve. I'll keep on reading and see if I can figure out how to implement it.

Comment: The really cool thing about this question and the excellent answers is that it demonstrates that the fact that a problem is NP is no reason to not try to solve it.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

#### I'd suggest you to use a Simulated annealing algorithm

And here is one nice solution derived by this algorithm:

```
[17, 16, 15, 9] 199:39
[3, 14, 10, 24] 199:50
[6, 8, 13, 21]  199:52
[1, 5, 20, 19]  199:55
[4, 23, 2, 18]  199:47
[11, 7, 22, 12] 199:51
```

As [Steven Skiena](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steven_Skiena) pointed in his book ("The Algorithm Design Manual"), that it is very helpful to use [Simulated annealing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simulated_annealing) metaheuristic for finding acceptable solutions in real life combinatorial problems.

So, as you mentioned, you need to put 4 tracks in each of 6 albums such that all albums will have approximately the same duration.

#### Firstly lets consider - which property do we need to optimize?

From my point of view - the most suitable formulation would be: *minimize [standard deviation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_Deviation) of durations of all albums.* (But, if needed - you are free to include any other, more complex, properties).

Let's name the value of an optimized property as **energy**.

#### The main idea of algorithm

Each state of our system is characterized by some value of energy. By performing some actions over the system we can change its state (e.g. Swapping tracks between different albums).

Also, we have some abstract property called **temperature**.

When system is under high temperature, it is free to change its state to another state, even if the new state has a higher value of energy.

But when the temperature is small, the system tends to change its state mostly to new states with lower values of energy.

By physical analogy, the probability of changing the current state of system to a state with a higher value of energy can be limited in the same way as [Boltzmann distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boltzmann_distribution) defines.

#### Here is an illustration of how the standard deviation of durations changed while deriving the solution from above

[image]

#### Here is a full Java implementation of algorithm, which gives the solution from above

```or-tag-here
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Random;

public class SimulatedAnnealingTracksOrdering {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int albumsCount = 6;
        int tracksInAlbum = 4;

        Album[] result = generateOptimalTracksOrdering(
                tracksInAlbum,
                albumsCount,
                new Track[] {
                        new Track(1, "39:03"), new Track(2, "41:08"),
                        new Track(3, "41:39"), new Track(4, "42:54"),
                        new Track(5, "44:31"), new Track(6, "44:34"),
                        new Track(7, "44:40"), new Track(8, "45:55"),
                        new Track(9, "45:59"), new Track(10, "47:06"),
                        new Track(11, "47:20"), new Track(12, "47:53"),
                        new Track(13, "49:35"), new Track(14, "49:57"),
                        new Track(15, "50:15"), new Track(16, "51:35"),
                        new Track(17, "51:50"), new Track(18, "55:45"),
                        new Track(19, "58:10"), new Track(20, "58:11"),
                        new Track(21, "59:48"), new Track(22, "59:58"),
                        new Track(23, "60:00"), new Track(24, "61:08"),
                });

        for (Album album : result) {
            System.out.println(album);
        }
    }

    private static Album[] generateOptimalTracksOrdering(
            int tracksInAlbum, int albumsCount, Track[] tracks) {

        // Initialize current solution
        Albums currentSolution =
                new Albums(tracksInAlbum, albumsCount, tracks);
        // Initialize energy of a current solution
        double currentEnergy =
                currentSolution.albumsDurationStandartDeviation();

        System.out.println("Current energy is: " + currentEnergy);

        // Also, we will memorize the solution with smallest value of energy
        Albums bestSolution = currentSolution.clone();
        double bestEnergy = currentEnergy;

        // Constant, which defines the minimal value of energy
        double minEnergy = 0.1;
        // Initial temperature
        double temperature = 150;
        // We will decrease value of temperature, by multiplying on this
        // coefficient
        double alpha = 0.999;
        // Constant, which defines minimal value of temperature
        double minTemperature = 0.1;
        // For each value of temperature - we will perform few probes, before
        // decreasing temperature
        int numberOfProbes = 100;

        Random random = new Random(1);

        while ((temperature > minTemperature)
                && (currentEnergy > minEnergy)) {

            for (int i = 0; i < numberOfProbes; i++) {
                // Generating new state
                currentSolution.randomTracksPermutation();
                double newEnergy =
                        currentSolution.albumsDurationStandartDeviation();

                // As defined by Boltzmann distribution
                double acceptanceProbability = 
                        Math.exp(-(newEnergy - currentEnergy) / temperature);

                // States with smaller energy - will be accepted always
                if ((newEnergy < currentEnergy)
                        || (random.nextDouble() < acceptanceProbability)) {

                    currentEnergy = newEnergy;
                    System.out.println("Current energy is: " + currentEnergy);

                    if (newEnergy < bestEnergy) {
                        bestSolution = currentSolution.clone();
                        bestEnergy = newEnergy;
                    }
                } else {
                    // If state can't be accepted - rollback to previous state
                    currentSolution.undoLastPermutation();
                }
            }
            // Decreasing temperature
            temperature *= alpha;
        }
        // Return best solution
        return bestSolution.getAlbums();
    }
}

/**
 * Container for bunch of albums
 */
class Albums {
    private Random random = new Random(1);
    private Album[] albums;
    // These fields, are used for memorizing last permutation
    // (needed for rollbacking)
    private Album sourceAlbum;
    private int sourceIndex;
    private Album targetAlbum;
    private int targetIndex;

    public Albums(int tracksInAlbum, int albumsCount, Track[] tracks) {
        // Put all tracks to albums
        this.albums = new Album[albumsCount];
        int t = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < albumsCount; i++) {
            this.albums[i] = new Album(tracksInAlbum);
            for (int j = 0; j < tracksInAlbum; j++) {
                this.albums[i].set(j, tracks[t]);
                t++;
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Calculating standard deviations of albums durations
     */
    public double albumsDurationStandartDeviation() {
        double sumDuration = 0;
        for (Album album : this.albums) {
            sumDuration += album.getDuraion();
        }
        double meanDuration =
                sumDuration / this.albums.length;

        double sumSquareDeviation = 0;
        for (Album album : this.albums) {
            sumSquareDeviation +=
                    Math.pow(album.getDuraion() - meanDuration, 2);
        }
        return Math.sqrt(sumSquareDeviation / this.albums.length);
    }

    /**
     * Performing swapping of random tracks between random albums
     */
    public void randomTracksPermutation() {
        this.sourceAlbum = this.pickRandomAlbum();
        this.sourceIndex =
                this.random.nextInt(this.sourceAlbum.getTracksCount());

        this.targetAlbum = this.pickRandomAlbum();
        this.targetIndex =
                this.random.nextInt(this.targetAlbum.getTracksCount());

        this.swapTracks();
    }

    public void undoLastPermutation() {
        this.swapTracks();
    }

    private void swapTracks() {
        Track sourceTrack = this.sourceAlbum.get(this.sourceIndex);
        Track targetTrack = this.targetAlbum.get(this.targetIndex);

        this.sourceAlbum.set(this.sourceIndex, targetTrack);
        this.targetAlbum.set(this.targetIndex, sourceTrack);
    }

    private Album pickRandomAlbum() {
        int index = this.random.nextInt(this.albums.length);
        return this.albums[index];
    }

    public Album[] getAlbums() {
        return this.albums;
    }

    private Albums() {
        // Needed for clonning
    }

    @Override
    protected Albums clone() {
        Albums cloned = new Albums();
        cloned.albums = new Album[this.albums.length];
        for (int i = 0; i < this.albums.length; i++) {
            cloned.albums[i] = this.albums[i].clone();
        }
        return cloned;
    }
}

/**
 * Container for tracks
 */
class Album {
    private Track[] tracks;

    public Album(int size) {
        this.tracks = new Track[size];
    }

    /**
     * Duration of album == sum of durations of tracks
     */
    public int getDuraion() {
        int acc = 0;
        for (Track track : this.tracks) {
            acc += track.getDuration();
        }
        return acc;
    }

    public Track get(int trackNum) {
        return this.tracks[trackNum];
    }

    public void set(int trackNum, Track track) {
        this.tracks[trackNum] = track;
    }

    public int getTracksCount() {
        return this.tracks.length;
    }

    public Track[] getTracks() {
        return this.tracks;
    }

    @Override
    protected Album clone() {
        Album cloned = new Album(this.tracks.length);
        for (int i = 0; i < this.tracks.length; i++) {
            cloned.tracks[i] = this.tracks[i];
        }
        return cloned;
    }

    /**
     * Displaying duration in MM:SS format
     */
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        int duraion = this.getDuraion();
        String duration_MM_SS = (duraion / 60) + ":" + (duraion % 60);
        return Arrays.toString(this.tracks) + "\t" + duration_MM_SS;
    }

}

class Track {
    private final int id;
    private final int durationInSeconds;

    public Track(int id, String duration_MM_SS) {
        this.id = id;
        this.durationInSeconds =
                this.parseDuration(duration_MM_SS);
    }

    /**
     * Converting MM:SS duration to seconds
     */
    private int parseDuration(String duration_MM_SS) {
        String[] parts = duration_MM_SS.split(":");
        return (Integer.parseInt(parts[0]) * 60)
                + Integer.parseInt(parts[1]);
    }

    public int getDuration() {
        return this.durationInSeconds;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return this.id;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return Integer.toString(this.id);
    }
}
```

Comment: I must admit most of that I did not actually understand, but what I know is that I tried your implementation with different sets of albums/running times and it produced very favorable results.

Answer (score 13):

This is equivalent* to [multiprocessor scheduling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiprocessor_scheduling) if you consider each album as a job and each playlist as a processor, and finding an optimal solution is NP-hard.

However, there are efficient algorithms which give decent but not necessarily optimal results. For example, sorting the albums by length and repeatedly adding the longest album to the shortest playlist.

If we number the albums from 1 to 24 from shortest to longest, this algorithm gives the following division.

```
{24, 13,  9,  6}  (201:16)
{23, 14, 12,  2}  (198:58)
{22, 15, 10,  4}  (200:13)
{21, 16,  8,  5}  (201:49)
{20, 17, 11,  3}  (199:00)
{19, 18,  7,  1}  (197:38)
```

* If we consider "evenly distributed" to mean that the length of the longest playlist is minimized.

Comment: Also known as "k-partition problem"

Comment: Basically +1, but the problem is only *equivalent* if you accept the same metric for "best division". MPSched is looking for the partition with the smallest maximum, while "as close to each other as possible" could well be, for example, the Euclidean norm (square root of the sum of the squares of the deviation from the mean). Just as difficult, I believe, but not always the same answer.

Comment: Most people would interpret it as minimizing absolute difference between the shortest and longest, which I believe is equivalent to minimizing the maximum length.

Comment: @hammar

I looked up mp schduling and it seems that the logic is simply to put the next job on the processor with the lightest load, which will achieve what I want to a certain degree, but I don't think it will result in the optimal solution.

See the division you presented above for example, if you swap Item # 8 in SET 4 (the longest playlist) and Item #7 in SET 6 (the shortest playlist), then SET 4 would be 200:34 and SET 6 would be 198:53, which would be a better distribution.

Comment: @heisenbergman: Yes, that is exactly what I said in my answer. Finding the optimal solution is NP-hard (grossly simplifed: we have good reason to believe there is no better algorithm than simply trying all `24! / (6! * (4!)^6) = 4509264634875` possible configurations), so I mentioned an efficient algorithm which gives an approximation.

Answer (score 4):

With a more intelligent search algorithm than brute force, we don't have to go through all 1e12 possibilities. First we convert the input, enumerate all sets of four, and sort them by their proximity to the target time.

```
import heapq
import itertools
import re

def secondsfromstring(s):
    minutes, seconds = s.split(':')
    return int(minutes) * 60 + int(seconds)

def stringfromseconds(seconds):
    minutes, seconds = divmod(seconds, 60)
    return '{}:{:02}'.format(minutes, seconds)

# for simplicity, these have to be pairwise distinct
stringtimes = '''39:03 41:08 41:39 42:54 44:31 44:34
                 44:40 45:55 45:59 47:06 47:20 47:53
                 49:35 49:57 50:15 51:35 51:50 55:45
                 58:10 58:11 59:48 59:58 60:00 61:08'''
times = [secondsfromstring(s) for s in stringtimes.split()]
quads = [frozenset(quad) for quad in itertools.combinations(times, 4)]
targettime = sum(times) / 6
quads.sort(key=lambda quad: abs(sum(quad) - targettime))
```

Now comes a search. We keep a priority queue with partial solutions, ordered by the minimum possible maximum deviation from the target time. The priority queue lets us explore the most promising partial solutions first.

```
queue = [(0, frozenset(times), [])]
while True:
    i, remaining, sofar = heapq.heappop(queue)
    if not remaining:
        for quad in sofar:
            print(stringfromseconds(sum(quad)), ':',
                  *(stringfromseconds(time) for time in quad))
        break
    while i < len(quads):
        quad = quads[i]
        if quad.issubset(remaining):
            heapq.heappush(queue, (i + 1, remaining, sofar))
            heapq.heappush(queue, (i + 1, remaining - quad, sofar + [quad]))
            break
        i += 1
```

In a couple seconds, this code spits out the following optimal answer. (We got lucky, since this code is working on the slightly modified objective of minimizing the maximum deviation from the target time; with the more complicated program below, we can minimize the difference between minimum and maximum, which turns out to be the same grouping.)

```
199:50 : 47:06 41:39 61:08 49:57
199:52 : 44:34 45:55 59:48 49:35
199:45 : 55:45 41:08 59:58 42:54
199:53 : 44:40 47:20 60:00 47:53
199:55 : 58:10 44:31 58:11 39:03
199:39 : 51:35 50:15 51:50 45:59
```

The program that optimizes the max minus min objective is below. Compared to the above program, it doesn't stop after the first solution but instead waits until we start considering sets whose deviation from the target is greater than the smallest max minus min of solutions that we have found so far. Then it outputs the best.

```
import heapq
import itertools
import re

def secondsfromstring(s):
    minutes, seconds = s.split(':')
    return int(minutes) * 60 + int(seconds)

def stringfromseconds(seconds):
    minutes, seconds = divmod(seconds, 60)
    return '{}:{:02}'.format(minutes, seconds)

# for simplicity, these have to be pairwise distinct
stringtimes = '''39:03 41:08 41:39 42:54 44:31 44:34
                 44:40 45:55 45:59 47:06 47:20 47:53
                 49:35 49:57 50:15 51:35 51:50 55:45
                 58:10 58:11 59:48 59:58 60:00 61:08'''
times = [secondsfromstring(s) for s in stringtimes.split()]
quads = [frozenset(quad) for quad in itertools.combinations(times, 4)]
targettime = sum(times) / 6
quads.sort(key=lambda quad: abs(sum(quad) - targettime))

def span(solution):
    quadtimes = [sum(quad) for quad in solution]
    return max(quadtimes) - min(quadtimes)

candidates = []
bound = None
queue = [(0, frozenset(times), [])]
while True:
    i, remaining, sofar = heapq.heappop(queue)
    if not remaining:
        candidates.append(sofar)
        newbound = span(sofar)
        if bound is None or newbound < bound: bound = newbound
    if bound is not None and abs(sum(quads[i]) - targettime) >= bound: break
    while i < len(quads):
        quad = quads[i]
        i += 1
        if quad.issubset(remaining):
            heapq.heappush(queue, (i, remaining, sofar))
            heapq.heappush(queue, (i, remaining - quad, sofar + [quad]))
            break
best = min(candidates, key=span)
for quad in best:
    print(stringfromseconds(sum(quad)), ':',
          *(stringfromseconds(time) for time in quad))
```

Answer (score 1):

This can be a comment too, but it is too long, so I post it as an answer. This is a little easy-to-code improvement to hammar's solution. This algorithm gives You no optimal solution, but it finds a better one.

You can start with hammar's greedy algorithm to fill the playlists with albums. Next all You have to do is looping through them few times. 
Let `D` the difference between the total length of playlist A and playlist B, where `length(A)>length(B)`. Loop through playlists A and B and if you find albums `x \in A` and `y \in B` which statisfies `x>y && x-y<D`, swap x and y.
This gave me the following results:

```
{7,8,22,13}   200:8
{2,11,24,15}  199:51
{4,10,23,14}  199:57
{3,17,12,19}  199:32
{5,16,21,6}   200:28
{1,18,9,20}   198:58
```

Answer (score 0):

For what it's worth, before stemm posted his Simulated annealing algorithm, I already had a solution which came to a close enough approximation of what I was looking for. So, just to share another (albeit relatively crude) approach, here it is:

(1) I sorted all of the individual track times from shortest to longest.

```
#01 - 39:03 
#02 - 41:08 
#03 - 41:39 
#04 - 42:54 
#05 - 44:31 
#06 - 44:34 
#07 - 44:40 
#08 - 45:55 
#09 - 45:59 
#10 - 47:06 
#11 - 47:20 
#12 - 47:53 
#13 - 49:35 
#14 - 49:57 
#15 - 50:15 
#16 - 51:35 
#17 - 51:50 
#18 - 55:45
#19 - 58:10 
#20 - 58:11 
#21 - 59:48 
#22 - 59:58   
#23 - 60:00 
#24 - 61:08
```

(2) I grouped into groups of 4 such that the resulting playlists would theoretically have as short a distance to each other just based on their positions on the sorted list, and that grouping would be: the shortest item + the longest item + the middle two items... then from the remaining (still sorted) list, again the shortest + the longest + the middle two items... so on and so forth until all items are grouped together.

(3) Using the resulting sets of 4 now, I iterate through all the individual albums in each of the sets, swapping out each item for every other item from the other sets. If, when swapped out, the distance of their source sets become smaller, then commit the swap. Else, skip the swap. Then I just did that repeatedly until no two albums can be swapped anymore to lessen the distance between their parent sets.

To illustrate step #3 in code:

```
Partitioner(){
    for(int i=0;i<total.length;i++)
        total[i] = 0;

    // get the total time for all sets of four albums
    for(int i=0;i<sets.length;i++){
        for(int j=0;j<sets[i].length;j++){
            total[i] = total[i] + sets[i][j];
        }
    }

    // this method will be called recursively until no more swaps can be done
    swapper();

    for(int i=0;i<sets.length;i++){
        for(int j=0;j<sets[i].length;j++){
            System.out.println(sets[i][j]);
        }
    }
}

void swapper(){
    int count = 0;  

    for(int i=0;i<sets.length;i++){ // loop through all the sets
        for(int j=0;j<sets[i].length;j++){ // loop through all the album in a set
            for(int k=0;k<sets.length;k++){ // for every album, loop through all the other sets for comparison
                if(k!=i){ // but of course, don't compare it to its own set
                    for(int l=0;l<sets[k].length;l++){ // pair the album (sets[i][j]) with every album from the other sets
                        int parentA = total[i]; // store the total length from the parent set of album sets[i][j] 
                        int parentB = total[k]; // store the total length from the parent set of the album being compared
                        int origDist = Math.abs(parentA - parentB); // measure the original distance between those two sets
                        int newA = total[i] - sets[i][j] + sets[k][l]; //compute new length of "parentA" if the two albums were swapped
                        int newB = total[k] - sets[k][l] + sets[i][j]; //compute new length of "parentB" if the two albums were swapped
                        int newdist = Math.abs(newA - newB); //compute new distance if the two albums were swapped
                        if(newdist<origDist){ // if the new resulting distance is less than the original distance, commit the swap
                            int temp = sets[i][j];
                            sets[i][j] = sets[k][l];
                            sets[k][l] = temp;
                            total[i] = newA;
                            total[k] = newB;
                            count++;

                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    System.out.println(count);
    if (count > 0 ){
        swapper();
    }
}
```